# Hover in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs

I have two components, let's say Parent and Child components

```
    import Child from "./Child";
     function Parent(){
      return(
       <div>
         <Child name="text1" />
         <Child name="text2" />
         <Child name="text3" />
      </div>
     );
    }
     export default Parent;
```

```
function Child(props){
  return(
   <div className="text-name">{props.name}</div>
  );
 }
  export default Child;
```

```
    .text-name{ color:red;}
    .text-name:hover{color: blue;}
```

Now  when I hover one of the Child component current component hovered blue. but how can I change my code in this way so that if i hover first child color should change on blue, for second one green, and for last one yellow.

Comment: do you mean the first time you hover it should be `blue` , the second time you hover it should be `green` and the third should be `yellow` ?

Comment: are you using `Sass` or `styled-components?`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass color props to Child component and use this props, Change your code like this.

```
import Child from "./Child";
 function Parent(){
  return(
   <div>
     <Child name="text1" color="blue" />
     <Child name="text2" color="green" />
     <Child name="text3" color="yellow" />
  </div>
 );
}
 export default Parent;
```

---

```
function Child({name, color}){
    return(
      <div className={`text-name ${color}`}>{name}</div>
    );
}
export default Child;
```

---

```
.text-name{ color:red;}
.blue:hover {
   color: blue;
}
.green:hover {
   color: green;
}
.yellow:hover {
   color: yellow;
}
```